# Sync SQL Server Database and VS DB Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, synchronization, ssms

I have a Visual Studio Database project and in the database I work in SSMS. After making changes in SSMS I want to apply the changes to the database project so it's in our Git repo (VSTS). How can I achieve that?